# Compile multiple C files so that resulant executables have the basename of the source file as their name

Tags: linux, gcc

I have the following C files in a directory...

```
hello.c, myprog.c, out.c
```

I want to compile these files in a single command such that the executables are named as follows:

```
hello, myprog, out
```

I tried this command

```
ls *.c | awk '{print $1}'
```

and this listed all the c files without extension.

Is it possible to pass these values to a variable through a pipe and use

```
| gcc $variable.c -o $variable
```

to produce the executables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in *.c; do  # or explicitly enumerate the files
    gcc -o `basename $i .c` $i
done
```

Comment: Basename does not strip filename extension, it just gets last component of a path.

Comment: @mity: actually it does, try it: `basename foo.c .c`

Comment: Oops. I overlooked the 2nd arg. That's new for me. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `make` installed, the build rules that are built in will be enough to build your binaries.

Just do `make hello` and you will get your binary. No need to explicitly call `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *.c ; do gcc $f -o `echo $f | sed "s/\.c$//"`; done
```

(not tested)

Comment: Easier to chop the name with bash string manipulation - `${f%.c}`